# I am trying to start an office program on a flash drive with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, kingsoft

I am putting Kingsoft office on my flash drive, and I want to use a batch file to start the applications because the paths are not easily accessible, I cannon create a .lnk file because the path varies by computer because it may be plugged into a different port. Here is my batch file code, could somebody give some suggestions on how to make this work. Thanks in advance...

```
set "path=%~dp0"
start %path%office6\wpp.exe
```

The second line is the problem, the program won't start the program. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing a backslash after `%path%`

Comment: don't use `path` as variable-name, because it's a systemvariable. Changing it, could lead to annoying results (well, not in your two-liner...)

Comment: If you put echo %path%  it displays C:\Users\Weston Miller\Desktop\Kingsoft Office\ and then I want to add office6\wpp.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
start "" /b wpp.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked except, how does that tell it where the office6 folder is, all I see is the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the directory names in **%path%** contain spaces and since **%path%** is not enclosed within **""**( double quotes), the script is unable to find the exe .

You may also want to include a log file so that it becomes easier to debug in case of any errors.

Try this:

```
set baseFolder=%~dp0
start "%baseFolder%office6\wpp.exe" > "%baseFolder%batchRunLog.log"
```

Comment: This did not work, The application didn't start and no errors were recorded in the log file.